# Remove the Google map labels

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to remove all the street names and other spots from Google Maps by using JS API.

I need just a map with no labels at all.

I tried adding Styled Map features of the v3 Maps API for removing labels, but it only works when I remove mapId and after removing mapId tilt and rotation doesn't work.

**code snippet:**

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.7893719,
      lng: -122.3942,
    },
    zoom: 16,
    heading: 320,
    tilt: 47.5,
    mapId: "90f87356969d889c",
    styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]}],
  });
  
  const buttons = [
    ["Rotate Left", "rotate", 20, google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER],
    ["Rotate Right", "rotate", -20, google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER],
    ["Tilt Down", "tilt", 20, google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER],
    ["Tilt Up", "tilt", -20, google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER],
  ];

  buttons.forEach(([text, mode, amount, position]) => {
    const controlDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const controlUI = document.createElement("button");

    controlUI.classList.add("ui-button");
    controlUI.innerText = `${text}`;
    controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
      adjustMap(mode, amount);
    });
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
    map.controls[position].push(controlDiv);
  });

  const adjustMap = function (mode, amount) {
    switch (mode) {
      case "tilt":
        map.setTilt(map.getTilt() + amount);
        break;
      case "rotate":
        map.setHeading(map.getHeading() + amount);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
}



window.initMap = initMap;
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the posted code, I get an error message that says:

> Google Maps JavaScript API: A Map's styles property cannot be set when a mapId is present. When a mapId is present Map styles are controlled via the cloud console. Please see documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#cloud_tooling

You need to remove the labels from the MapOptions and add them in the cloud styling tool, per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/cloud-customization/overview#before-you-begin):

> - **Migrate from legacy styling** 
>   Before adding a map ID to use Cloud-based maps styling on an existing map that is customized with hard-coded styling, such as JSON or URL query parameters, we recommend you remove the hard-coded styling to avoid potential conflict with future functionality. You can [import your JSON styling into a new map style](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/cloud-customization/map-styles#import-json-styling).

See [that link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/cloud-customization/map-styles#import-json-styling)

[image: screenshot of map]

**Code Snippet (modified mapId style to remove labels):**

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.7893719,
      lng: -122.3942,
    },
    zoom: 16,
    heading: 320,
    tilt: 47.5,
    mapId: "1328f4a9138013ba",
  });

  const buttons = [
    ["Rotate Left", "rotate", 20, google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER],
    ["Rotate Right", "rotate", -20, google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER],
    ["Tilt Down", "tilt", 20, google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER],
    ["Tilt Up", "tilt", -20, google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER],
  ];

  buttons.forEach(([text, mode, amount, position]) => {
    const controlDiv = document.createElement("div");
    const controlUI = document.createElement("button");

    controlUI.classList.add("ui-button");
    controlUI.innerText = `${text}`;
    controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
      adjustMap(mode, amount);
    });
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
    map.controls[position].push(controlDiv);
  });

  const adjustMap = function(mode, amount) {
    switch (mode) {
      case "tilt":
        map.setTilt(map.getTilt() + amount);
        break;
      case "rotate":
        map.setHeading(map.getHeading() + amount);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
}



window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

    body {
      font-family: arial;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>remove labels from map</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```